# Add a static library for the link phase of a Maven NAR project

Tags: c++, maven, opencv, maven-plugin

I've packaged an already compiled version of [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to a NAR Maven project. I've followed https://github.com/CERN/narlibs-log4cplus to achieve this (a project that only contains .lib, .dll and .h files). This is my final directory structure (the `lib` directory contains the .lib and .dll files and the directory `include` contains the .h files):

[image: NAR packaged version of OpenCV]

The `pom.xml` file:

```
...
<groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
<artifactId>opencv-nar</artifactId>
<packaging>nar</packaging>
<version>2.4.10</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
            <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <libraries>
                    <library>
                        <type>static</type>
                    </library>
                    <library>
                        <type>shared</type>
                    </library>
                </libraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am using this dependency on a simple project:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is happening in the link phase (after executing `mvn compile -X`).

```
...
[DEBUG] FileSet: Setup scanner in dir E:\PROY\image-lib\dev\1.0\image\target\nar\opencv-nar-2.4.10-x86-Windows-msvc-shared\lib\x86-Windows-msvc\shared with patternSet{ includes: [opencv-nar-2.4.10.lib] excludes: [] }
...
[DEBUG] Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'link' with arguments:
'/MANIFEST'
'/NOLOGO'
'/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE'
'/INCREMENTAL:NO'
'/OUT:image.exe'
'C:\image\target\nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc\image-test.obj'
[INFO] image-test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
[ERROR] image-test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
[INFO] image.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
[ERROR] image.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For what I see the problem is because none of the static libs from OpenCv are passed to the 'link' arguments. So, *How do I add a static library (or better, a directory) to the `link` arguments?*

```
opencv_core2410.lib
opencv_imgproc2410.lib
opencv_highgui2410.lib
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an aswer, but more of a way around. I believe that by te way MAVEN NAR  is designed (even MAVEN itself) *every* library has to be on its own project.

So, with this in mind you need to generate a project based on these 2 projects:

- https://github.com/markjohndoyle/boost-nar - The parent structure and the project divided in modules
- https://github.com/CERN/narlibs-log4cplus - The file structure (which I've already used)

So, for my OpenCV project, this is the parent `pom.xml`, which is based on  [parent pom.xml from Boost C++ libraries in maven form](https://github.com/markjohndoyle/boost-nar/blob/master/pom.xml), for a [list of compiler names for the NAR plugin see in aol.properties](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/blob/nar-maven-plugin-3.2.2/src/main/resources/com/github/maven_nar/aol.properties):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.10</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>OpenCV :: Parent</name>
    <description>OpenCV</description>

    <properties>
        <nar-plugin.version>3.2.3</nar-plugin.version>
        <compiler-name>msvc</compiler-name>
        <linker-name>msvc</linker-name>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>highgui</module>
        <module>imgproc</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${nar-plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <cpp>
                        <name>${compiler-name}</name>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.hpp</include>
                            <include>**/*.h</include>
                            <include>**/*.cpp</include>
                            <include>**/*.c</include>
                        </includes>
                    </cpp>
                    <linker>
                        <name>${linker-name}</name>
                    </linker>
                    <libraries>
                        <library>
                            <type>static</type>
                        </library>
                        <library>
                            <type>shared</type>
                        </library>
                    </libraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And each module has a `pom.xml` file that more or less resembled this:

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>opencv-core</artifactId>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <name>OpenCV :: Core</name>
    <description>OpenCV</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, you will have to add the respective dependencies in your project `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv-highgui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv-imgproc</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And there you have:

```
> mvn compile
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```